# Solution to why Firefox doesnt work percentage height

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this one in Firefox:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJpwEj

For some reason it shrinks in Firefox, like it can't calculate the height.

Both Chrome and Edge shows it correctly but for Firefox to show the same result I need to set height to 90vh like its parent.

css as follows: changing height: 100% to 90vh works. But I dont understand why.

```
.themes-outercontainer
{
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
}

.themes-container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: try setting a `min-height` value?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.themes-container` is overriding by a  `display: flex`, so your `display: table-cell` is not applied. You can't manage `height` property on this way when you use flexbox attributes.

The other problem is that `.themes-whiteoverlay` is `position: absolute` so the height doesn't work as you expected.

Please, try to think what's your preference: flexbox or table, and try to remove absolute positioning if you don't know how it works.

Comment: the problem is that I need to support a fallback when flex isnt availible. so chosing one isn't really an option

Answer (score -1):

Unlike other browsers, Firefox doesn't assume the actual height of the screen, so it has to use viewpoint height units to figure that out. The only exception to this I believe is the body element

For instance, let's say that you're given a question in Math. The teacher wants you to find what 50% of an unknown number is. How would you do that? You can't, so you have to ask for the number.

Comment: Firefox assumes the height of the outercontainer which is the weird part that it can't use that.

Comment: @indiehjaerta Sorry, I'm confused. What can't use what?